# How to find an element by data selector in an array of HTML DOM objects using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, selector

I've an array of HTML DOM objects:

```
// Console output

(3) […]
0: <div data-selector="5">​
1: <div data-selector="9">​
2: <div data-selector="2">​
3: <div data-selector="6">​
4: <div data-selector="13">​
length: 5
<prototype>: Array []
```

How can I find (and return) the HTML object having `data-selector` equal to `9` (i.e.`<div data-selector="9">​`) using JavaScript?

Comment: How does this array get logged? Do you have control over the code that logs the array?

Comment: Do you get this array from an outside source, or construct on your own (by selecting elements). If latter is the case, then its better to utilize the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and select only the desired element. That will be efficient.

Comment: I've no control over the code that gets the array. I get this array from an outside source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would solve your problem.

```
array.find(item => item.dataset.selector === '9');
```

> Explanation:
>
> Javascript allows you to use `dataset` to access data attributes in html. That is, they have a pattern such as `data-*`

So, if you have a html file that looks like this:

```
<html>
  <div id="root">
    <div data-selector="5"></div>
    <div data-selector="9"></div>
    <div data-selector="2"></div>
    <div data-selector="6"></div>
    <div data-selector="13"></div>
  </div>
</html>
```

You can get the `div` with id of root in your javascript file:

```
const root = document.querySelector('#root');

// get array of div elements inside root
const tagsArray = [...root.children];

// finally, retrieve the specific element you need
const selectedItem = tagsArray.find(elem => elem.dataset.selector === '9');

// A simple check
console.log(selectedItem); // => <div data-selector="9"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `querySelectorAll` function and specify the attribute ie: `data-selector` and assign the value which is `9`.

Note: The `querySelectorAll` function returns an array of elements.

```js
const x = document.querySelectorAll("[data-selector='9']");
console.log(x[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<p data-selector="9">Test</p>
```

Comment: I get this array from an outside source and do not have control over the code that gets it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that Using `getAttribute()` method

```
var myArray // Let this be your array
var len = myArray.length
// Implement this logic
for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    if(myArray[i].getAttribute('data-selector') == '9') {
        // Return myArray[i] or do what ever you want to do
    }
}
```

Comment: se my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
// Array of HTML DOM objects:
var myArray = ['<div data-selector="5">', '...', '<div data-selector="9">'];

var found = myArray.find(function(element) {
  return element.getAttribute('data-selector') === '9';
});
```

Based on `getAttribute()` by @vaibhav kumar

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this (where `array` is your array of HTML elements):

```js
array.forEach(element => {
  if(element.getAttribute("data-selector") == "9") doSomething(element);
});
```

If the array's `data-selector` attribute is equal to `"9"`, the function `doSomething()` gets executed and passed the element.

Comment: It doesn't return the desired element.